# How to add my custom android application on to the Android software stack?

Tags: android

I have one requirement to add my custom application on to the Android software stack where all core application are added (Home, Calendar,Contacts etc...), so it will always be a part of core application and when user will switch on the device they can find my custom application also available on the home screen.

Now my doubt is how to take the image of android software stack and how to update it with my custom application, if I am able to do it then I can ask device manufacturer to use the updated android software stack.

Can anyone is having any idea regarding this?
any help will be appreciable.

Regards,
Piks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do mean with "on to the Android software stack" ?

If you wrote an app, users can easily have your app on their home screen. But afaik you, as app developer, wont be able to place the app there (e.g. without the user).

Comment: My main intention is to make the app as part of android software stack like how other core applications available, so if I am able to add my app to the stack then when this android software stack will be deployed to the new mobile device then my app will automatically will be available in to the device and like user can't remove any of those core app, my app will also not be removable. Hope this will clarify your doubt.

Comment: In Theory: 
Get full android source code, code your app and include it into android. Then you would only have to bring your own Android on to the devices you need.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, it seems like this process is bit tedious one to include my app in android stack.As I am new in android so not aware about the actual process to add my app in android open source so if you know something about it then pls do help me.

Comment: If i could, i would! =) 
But i bet there are some hackers in the wild that already cooked their own android and published experiences.

Comment: ohhh....then I appeal to all experienced hackers/android publishers, please help me to include my custom app to android open source code.